# Storing array of heterogeneous keypaths

Tags: swift, keypaths, swift-keypath

I have an object similar to:

```
class MyObject {
  var title:String? = nil
  var value:Int? = nil
  var otherData:[String] = []
}
```

I am attempting to store a heterogeneous array of updates so I can use them later to set values. Something like this.

```
class SomeFormThing {
  func getUpdates() -> [WritableKeyPath<MyObject, Any> : Any] {
    var updates:[WritableKeyPath<MyObject, Any> : Any]
    updates[\MyObject.title] = "New Title"
    updates[\MyObject.value] = 0
    updates[\MyObject.value] = ["Other", "Values"]
    return updates
  }
}

class SyncManager {
  var form:SomeFormThing = SomeFormThing()
  var sync:MyObject = MyObject()
  func updateValues() {
    let updates = form.getUpdates()
    for key in updates.keys {
      sync[forKeyPath: key] = updates[key]
    }
  }
}
```

However, this of course has a compile problem on the lines in getUpdates() that read `Cannot convert value of type 'WritableKeyPath<MyObject, String?>' to expected argument type 'WritableKeyPath<MyObject, Any>'`.

The need is to have an array of heterogeneous writable keypaths that I can then use to set values. Given how generics typically work, I don't see why String is not able to equate to the Any generic, since the type is a downcast.

Comment: Swift generics are not covariant, you cannot cast them.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have tried that. That yields the same issue.

Comment: @vadian Then how would I accomplish what I am attempting, a heterogenous dictionary of keypaths with values.

Comment: Basically you can't. This has always been an issue with key paths, because it is how generics work. You can type erase, of course - this is exactly what partial key paths are for - but where will that get you? Basically what you want to do here is against the whole spirit of Swift: key paths give you type safety and you are asking to throw that away.

Comment: @matt So, essentially, unless you can conform to an NSObject and use string keys with .setValue, Swift gives no way to reflexively and dynamically set values base on key:value pairs for an object? And, in this case, I can't use NSObject's .setValue because it does not work with optionals. That seems like a massive oversight for reflection-based code.

Comment: There is no reflection here. That's the point. If you wanted a language without type safety, with heterogeneous collections, and with introspective dynamism, you would have been using Objective-C (or Ruby or something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift collections don't like to be heterogenous. Moreover, keypaths are generics, for type safety, and generics are not covariant.

So you cannot combine different types in one collection — unless you type-erase. Of course, if you do that, you have to *un* type erase later, which is a pain in the butt. It's like a roach motel: wrapped types go in but they don't come out unless you elicit them by hand.

For example:

```
    struct MyObject {
      var title:String
      var value:Int
    }

    // okay, roaches go in...
    let kp1 = \MyObject.title
    let kp2 = \MyObject.value
    let dict : [PartialKeyPath<MyObject>:Any] = [kp1:"Yo", kp2:1]

    var object = MyObject(title: "Ha", value: 0)

    // but now what? how can we apply our `dict` entries to `object`? well...
    for (kp,val) in dict {
        switch (kp,val) {
        case (let kp2 as WritableKeyPath<MyObject,String>, let val2 as String):
            object[keyPath:kp2] = val2
        case (let kp2 as WritableKeyPath<MyObject,Int>, let val2 as Int):
            object[keyPath:kp2] = val2
        default:break
        }
    }
    print(object) // yep, we did it, sort of
```

So you see, you can do it, but you'd have to deal individually with every possible property type. You've hidden the types in the Partial of PartialKeyPath and in the Any, and now forcing them out into the open is up to you.

That said, the way I would actually do this is to give MyObject a generic `update` method and just call it one change at a time:

```
    struct MyObject {
        var title:String
        var value:Int
        mutating func update<T>(_ kp:WritableKeyPath<Self,T>, to val:T) {
            self[keyPath:kp] = val
        }
    }
```

And so:

```
    object.update(\.title, to: "Teehee")
    object.update(\.value, to: 42)
```

Note that you cannot do that directly from an entry in the `dict` because you've hidden the types. A generic doesn't wait until runtime to look to see what type something "really" is; it is resolved by the compiler, so the type must be known — and by saying PartialKeyPath and Any you have made the type *un* known.

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation here. Yeah having to deal with individual property types as a cast is going to be a huge pain. I've considered a suggestion a similar generics typing problem by using closures, but that's a bit of a mess too. I'm actually pretty surprised Swift doesn't have a comparable pattern for `setValue` like the objc stuff did. I'm slowly learning that Swift's reflections is just not as powerful as its predecessor.

Comment: See my (new) comment on the question. Why are you surprised? What you are asking to do is opposed to the entire spirit of Swift. We're lucky to have key paths at all, if you ask me. Now, that said, I have certainly done updating of objects view key paths; but you just have to use a generic and take them one by one.

Comment: Just read that. Yeah, Keypaths are technically not reflection, but they are sold as the Swift way to handle reflection-like functionality. It's just unfortunate that Apple's flagship language is lacking in this area.

Comment: Well, if you take them one at a time instead of making a collection like that, you can just keep calling a generic `update` method. That's what I would actually do.

Comment: Yeah I'm working on a remote sync manager that allows a transient object (non synced) and an array of updates that are applied when needed (on form submit) and then fired off async to an API. So users can maintain a running edit of an object but not have to wait for the API request to return to continue. It's been a bit of a bear, but using closures or a giant nasty update switch to wedge key:value updating into my object may be my only options.

Comment: Essentially, I'm maintaining two versions of the object. One non-synced and one synced. I'm also managing an array of non-synced updates as keypath:value. That way I can maintain the transient object while the API call for the synced object fires off. Then, on success, it can wipe the update queue and normalize my sync and transient, then (if any non synced updates remain) fire those off as well until there are none left.